# jQuery input with same name and square brackets

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that is using jQuery and Ajax to post the form data, but cannot get it to send the values of inputs with the same name and square brackets.

The inputs look like this and will have different values:

```
<input type="text" name="service[]" value="Value 1">
```

Here is the var for getting the value:

```
var service = $("input[name=service\\[\\]]")
```

Then the var for collecting the data to send via Ajax looks like this:

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&service=' + service.val() + '&brief='  + encodeURIComponent(brief.val());
```

Then in the PHP script for sending the mail includes the following...

```
$service = $_POST['service'];
$body .= implode(' | ', $service);
```

So my question is, how do I get the values of the inputs with the name `name=service[]` and send them via Ajax.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Stuart, if one of this questions solved your problem please click to accept them.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer to your question, but there is an easier way to do this.

Wrap your input-fields in a form and make an `on-submit`-event. Return this event false so it's not actually submitted.

Here's the trick. Before you return the event false, do the ajax-request. Give the form an id and use the seralize-method to make a json-string.

```
[...]
data: $('#formIDGoesHere').serialize(),
[...]
```

If you post this to your PHP file as POST-variables, all your values are not available like they normally would be in  `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this?

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' 
           + phone.val() + '&service=' + service.val() + '&brief=' 
           + encodeURIComponent(brief.val());
```

You shall not build strings from unescaped values. This is true for HTML, and it is true for URL-encoded form data and SQL and JSON and virtually every other way that transports structured data in string form.

Apparently you are using `encodeURIComponent()`, but why only once?

There is [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which takes care of all the details. Use that instead of building your own URL string.

```
alert($('form').serialize());
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! I am quite new to jQuery/Ajax and I got the code from a script online, I didn't know about `.serialize()`

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're still a beginner, it's a very good time to internalize this ultimate truth: Whenever you build something that has structure (like HTML or SQL, as mentioned above) by concatenating strings, an instant stomach pain should remind you that you are probably doing something wrong. **All cross-site-scripting and injection  vulnerabilities and many bugs are a result of careless string building.** Search the framework you are using for ways to avoid string building. Most of these problems have been solved, don't roll your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read **[this](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/)** and try this:

```
$('#theFormID').serialize().replace('%5B%5D', '[]')
```

or this

```
$.param(obj, true);
$.post(url,serializedObj,function(){});
```

The `true` in the `$.param` indicates the traditional method of serializing an object should be used. The traditional method does not use square brackets when it encounters the same parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like:

```
var values = $("input[name='service\\[\\]']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

var joined = values.join("|"); //so it shows val1|val2| val3 .. and pass to server
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple inputs with the name service[] you can retrieve the inputs like the one below

```
var service = $("input[name=service\\[\\]]");
```

but if you have multiple inputs now service variable is an array  now you have to loop thru each item in the service array and retrieve the values like

```
for(var i=0;i<service.length;i++){
  data += service[i].val()+",";
}
```